# How to create BigQuery table with required fields from DataFlow with string schema definition?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I am using DataFlow's `WriteToBigQuery` with `CREATE_IF_NEEDED`, and thus have to specify the schema.

I define the schema in the beginning of my code (outside the actual pipeline), but since I need the flag `--save_main_session`, I get the same error as [here](https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-3134), which explains that the schema cannot be passed along with the pipeline since a BigQuery schema definition is not pickleable.

The solution mentioned on the page is not an option for me (disable the `--save_main_session` flag), and thus the [other option](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/google-bigquery/#creating-a-table-schema) to specify the schema is through a string. 
However, I need to set some fields to `REQUIRED`. Is there a way to do this with the string schema definition?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from [bigquery.py](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.py#L700-L725) the conversion from a string schema to a TableSchema is quite straightforward and does indeed set the mode to NULLABLE. Perhaps you can create the TableSchema with REQUIRED fields based on this code snippet.

Comment: Thanks for linking the code. It would be a small adjustment in that snippet to include REQUIRED flags. But I cannot generate the TableSchema myself because it is not pickleable. Do you have an idea how to circumvent this?

Comment: Can you express the schema in another format, e.g. JSON, pass that to your code, and only convert it to a `TableSchema` afterwards?